# Adding Typescript declaration for package with inner modules

Tags: typescript, tsc

I am wanting to add types to a component library written purely in Javascript that I am not currently able to add directly to. I have followed this example for [adding declarations to third party packages](https://medium.com/@chris_72272/migrating-to-typescript-write-a-declaration-file-for-a-third-party-npm-module-b1f75808ed2), which almost got me there. The current issue I am having is the package structure.

The package is located in `node_modules` as `@company/company-widgets`, I am not exactly certain how to handle the inner module as `tsc` is unable to find and associate the declaration files I have added. The compiler's recommendation is

`` Try `npm install @types/company__company-widgets` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'company__company-widgets';` ``

I have tried the following:

1. Modifying `tsconfig.json` with `"typeRoots": ["@types", "./src/@types"] and adding an`index.d.ts` file with the module declaration specified in the compiler message
2. With the above `tsconfig.json` changes, adding directories under `src/@types` to match that of `node_modules`
3. I also changed the declaration to have a `module` named **company** and a `namespace` of **__company-widgets**
4. I also got desparate and started messing around with `node_modules` by placing a declaration in there

None of these have got the declaration found unfortunately, so I have been thinking it is unable to associate the module name in the declaration to the package name. 
Any suggestions or answers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler's recommendation is wrong: the module declaration should be `declare module '@company/company-widgets';`, not `declare module 'company__company-widgets';`.  I [fixed this recently](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26121) and the fix should be in TypeScript 3.1.